# form_button() in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, json, function, codeigniter

I just want to create button like this using [form helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_button) (with apostrophe [ `'` ])

```
<button type="button" data-button='{"func": "func1"}'>click1</button>
```

but when implement with some code :

```
form_button(array(
    'data-button' => '{"func": "func1"}',
    'content' => 'click1',
    )
)
```

the result is (with quote [ `"` ] )

```
<button type="button" data-button="{"func": "func1"}">click1</button>
```

and I'm tryin to inspect element, the result is :

```
<button type="button" data-button="{" func":"func1"}"="">click1</button>
```

and when button click, JSON in button says that syntax error with [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse)

Comment: Have you tried using &#39; without using ' ?

Comment: How to place `&#39;` ?

Comment: &#39; is the html character code for '.
You can replace ' with &#39; wherever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things,

1. form_button accepts 3 parameters,

   ```
   form_button([$data = ''[, $content = ''[, $extra = '']]])
   ```

   So, your function should be

   ```
   form_button('', 'click1', array(
           'data-button' => json_encode(array('func'=>'func1'))
       )
   );
   ```
2. The form helper library has some issue with it, to resolve, navigate to folder, `your_project/system/helpers/form_helper.php`, find function `_attributes_to_string`, find line which says,

   ```
   $atts .= ' '.$key.'="'.$val.'"';,
   ```

   change it to

   ```
   $atts .= ' '.$key.'="'.html_escape($val).'"';
   ```

This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Change from

```
form_button(array(
    'data-button' => '{"func":"func1"}',
    'content' => 'click1',
    )
)
```

To

```
$dbutton = array("func" => "func");

$data =array(
        'data-button' =>json_encode($dbutton),
        'content' => 'click1',
       );

form_button($data);
```

Comment: `url_title()` make `{"func": "func1"}` to `func-func1` :(

Answer (score 0):

simple method, just escape string html like `htmlspecialchars()`.
In Codeigniter 4 `esc()`.

```
form_button([
    'data-button' => esc('{"func": "func1"}'),
    'content' => 'click1',
]);
```